# Which one of the options would be more accurate to use?

Tags: word-usage

In natural science, there were nearly as many women [approximately 200] as men [approximately 240] . This was also true ***in / for / of / when it comes to*** psychology.

or This also holds true ***to/for*** psychology

which one of the prepositions in bold or sentences would be more proper(or you'd prefer) to use in the sentence above?

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of your options work. There can sometimes be a little overlap with prepositions, though they each give a slightly different impression.

> **1:** This was also true **in** psychology.

This option is grammatically correct and doesn't sound unnatural, but this wording is preferable when we're talking about something actually within the field of psychology, rather than an aspect of your psychology department. (Ex. *In natural science it is always important to consider where something comes from before trying to analyse it. **This is also true in psychology**, where different cultures can shape individuals differently.*)

If we talk about the psychology *department* however, this becomes a perfectly acceptable preposition. (Ex. *In the natural science department there were nearly as many women as men. **This was also true in the psychology department.***) Now we are talking about a place or construct *within which* this statement is also true.

> **2:** This was also true **for** psychology.

*For* can be used to mean *in respect to* which certainly makes sense here.

*For* has other definitions as well which gives the potential for ambiguity in a sentence with the same construct but different nouns. For example, "*It was true for his mother*" could be used to mean "it" is something his mother considers true, rather than something true about her. This confusion is mitigated with context, however, and I still maintain that *for* is a perfectly acceptable choice.

> **3:** This was also true **of** psychology.

Much like *for*, *of* can be used to mean *in respect to*. In this construct there is nothing else that *of* could mean and so there is no ambiguity at all.

While I think *true for X* is said plenty out loud, *true of X* is slightly more formal sounding, and ([according to ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+is+also+true+for%2C+this+is+also+true+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20is%20also%20true%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20is%20also%20true%20of%3B%2Cc0)) definitely the more popular choice in written works.

(You can also see from that graph that the use of *of* is much older, but on the decline, while *for* is newer and was on the rise until the mid 80s. That would certainly explain why *of* sounds more formal.)

> **4:** This was also true **when it came to** psychology.

I changed your example slightly -- this *was* true is in the past tense, so it must be *came* and not *comes*. This removes any confusion by just skipping the preposition problem entirely. It is also a perfectly valid option.

> **5:** This also holds true **for** psychology.

A slight rewording, but for the same reasons *for* worked above, it works here. (Note: the for/of relationship is the same here, [but much stronger](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this%20holds%20true%20for%2C%20this%20holds%20true%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20holds%20true%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20holds%20true%20of%3B%2Cc0). Avoid saying "*this holds true of psychology*" as it has pretty much gone out of general usage.)

> **✘:** This also holds true **to** psychology.

Of all your options, this is the only one which is incorrect. For something to be "true **to** X" is a different meaning of *true* entirely and does not work here at all.

You can feel free to pick from any of the other options, however. If you still want more specific advice, I'd go with "**This was also true of psychology.**

Comment: one of the best answers I've got so far. - explanatory, inclusionary and exemplary in all respect. Really deserves more than just typing +1.